# Transforming XML File to Flat File Format

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm looking for the other references regarding the transformation of XML file to Flat File format and I have seen many of them. I've tried some of the codes that I saw over the internet and it helps a lot. I tried to do my own XSLT file and I can't get what I want in my output. Also, I need to minimize my coding in the XSLT since I have a lot of coding and condition to applied from Header Record, Detail/Contra Record and Trailer. The value of the header record is correct, however, 2nd and 3rd row of the current output is incorrect. I need to populate for every Transaction there should have 1 detail and 1 Contra. The output should look like what's on the expected output.

Thank you.

**SAMPLE XML FILE**

```
<SyncCreditTransfer xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" releaseID="9.2" versionID="2.12.3" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2 http://schema.infor.com/2.12.x/InforOAGIS/BODs/SyncCreditTransfer.xsd">
<Application>
    <Sender>
        <LogicalID>company department</LogicalID>
    </Sender>
    <CreationDateTime>2016-07-01T05:50:16.208Z</CreationDateTime>
</Application>
<Data>
    <Sync>
        <ID>1122EDF6394</ID>
        <EntityID>SampleFiele</EntityID>
    </Sync>
    <Record>
        <Header>
            <DateTime>2016-07-01T05:51:16</DateTime>
        </Header>
        <Payment>
            <DisplayID>Payment1: 09459732</DisplayID>
            <DebtorParty>
                <FinancialAccount>
                    <ID>11111</ID>
                </FinancialAccount>
            </DebtorParty>
            <Transaction sequence="1">
                <TransactionID>BOA-t-121212</TransactionID>
                <InstructedAmount currencyID="EUR">123.43</InstructedAmount>
                <CreditorParty>
                    <FinancialAccount>
                        <ID>AAAAA</ID>
                    </FinancialAccount>
                </CreditorParty>
            </Transaction>
            <Transaction sequence="1">
                <TransactionID>BOA-t-343434</TransactionID>
                <InstructedAmount currencyID="GBP">123.43</InstructedAmount>
                <CreditorParty>
                    <FinancialAccount>
                        <ID>BBBBB</ID>
                    </FinancialAccount>
                </CreditorParty>
            </Transaction>
        </Payment>
        <Payment>
            <DisplayID>Payment2: 12435435</DisplayID>
            <DebtorParty>
                <FinancialAccount>
                    <ID>22222</ID>
                </FinancialAccount>
            </DebtorParty>
            <Transaction sequence="1">
                <TransactionID>BOA-t-090909</TransactionID>
                <InstructedAmount currencyID="EUR">123.43</InstructedAmount>
                <CreditorParty>
                    <FinancialAccount>
                        <ID>AAAAA</ID>
                    </FinancialAccount>
                </CreditorParty>
            </Transaction>
            <Transaction sequence="1">
                <TransactionID>BOA-t-878787</TransactionID>
                <InstructedAmount currencyID="GBP">123.43</InstructedAmount>
                <CreditorParty>
                    <FinancialAccount>
                        <ID>BBBBB</ID>
                    </FinancialAccount>
                </CreditorParty>
            </Transaction>
        </Payment>
    </Record>
</Data>
```

**XSLT FILE**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:func="myfunc">
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:function name="func:trunc">
    <xsl:param name="str"/>
    <xsl:param name="len"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($str,1,$len)"/>
</xsl:function>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- Start of Header Record -->
    <xsl:element name="UserHeadLabel">
        <xsl:text>UHL</xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="Constant01">
        <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="Filler01">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="PaymentDate">
        <xsl:if test="//*:Header/*:DateTime[normalize-space()]!=''">
            <xsl:value-of select="func:trunc(//*:Header/*:DateTime,5)"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="Constant02">
        <xsl:text>999999</xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="Filler02">
        <xsl:text>    </xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="CurrencyCode">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="//*:Payment/*:Transaction/*:InstructedAmount/@currencyID[normalize-space()]!='' and //*:Payment/*:Transaction/*:InstructedAmount/@currencyID='EUR'">
                <xsl:text>01</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>00</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="Constant03">
        <xsl:text>000000</xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="Constant04">
        <xsl:text>1 DAILY  </xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="FileNumber">
        <xsl:text>001</xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="Filler03">
        <xsl:text>   </xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="Optional01">
        <xsl:text>       </xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="Optional02">
        <xsl:text>   </xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="UserOptional">
        <xsl:text>000000000000</xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <!-- End of Header Record -->

    <!-- Start of Detail Record -->
        <xsl:element name="DestinationSortCodeNo">
            <xsl:if test="//*:Payment/*:Transaction/*:CreditorParty/*:FinancialAccount/*:ID[normalize-space()]!=''">
                <xsl:value-of select="//*:Payment/*:Transaction/*:CreditorParty/*:FinancialAccount/*:ID"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="DestinationAccountNo">
            <xsl:if test="//*:Payment/*:Transaction/*:TransactionID[normalize-space()]!=''">
                <xsl:value-of select="//*:Payment/*:Transaction/*:TransactionID"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="Zero01">
        <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="TransactionCode">
        <xsl:text>99</xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <!-- End of Detail Record -->

    <!-- Start of Contra Record -->
        <xsl:element name="UserSortCodeNo1">
            <xsl:if test="//*:Payment/*:DebtorParty/*:FinancialAccount/*:ID[normalize-space()]!=''">
                <xsl:value-of select="//*:Payment/*:DebtorParty/*:FinancialAccount/*:ID"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="UserAccountNo1">
            <xsl:if test="//*:Payment/*:DisplayID[normalize-space()]!=''">
                <xsl:value-of select="//*:Payment/*:DisplayID"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="Zero01">
        <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="TransactionCode">
        <xsl:text>17</xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <!-- End of Contra Record -->
</xsl:template>
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
UHL1 2016-999999    010000001 DAILY  001             000000000000
AAAAA BBBBB CCCCC DDDDDBOA-t-121212 BOA-t-343434 BOA-t-090909 BOA-t-878787099
11111 22222Payment1: 09459732 Payment2: 12435435017
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
UHL1 2016-999999    010000001 DAILY  001             000000000000
AAAAAABOA-t-12099
11111MPayment1017
BBBBBMBOA-t-34099
11111MPayment1017
CCCCCMBOA-t-09099
22222MPayment2017
DDDDDMBOA-t-87099
22222MPayment2017
```

**Explanation:** The value **AAAAAA** comes from the *Payment/Transaction/CreditorParty/FinancialAccount/ID* and should only have 6 characters. The **BOA-t-12** comes from the *Payment/Transaction/TransactionID* and this field should only have 8characters. **0** is the hardcoded value, as well as, the value **99**. On the next line, the **11111M** comes from the *Payment/DebtorParty/FinancialAccount/ID*, **Payment1** is from the *Payment/DisplayID* and **0** and **17** are the hardcoded value. From the next line and soon, it will only repeat the process and this time the value will be get from the next occurrence of Payment/Transaction.

For every occurrence of Payment/Transaction, it will create 1 Detail record and 1 Contra record. In my example, I have 4 Transaction, and the output should have:

```
Detail - 1st occurrence of Transaction
Contra - 1st occurrence of Transaction
Detail - 2nd occurrence
Contra - 2nd occurrence
Detail - 3rd occurrence
Contra - 3rd occurrence
Detail - 4th occurrence
Contra - 4th occurrence
```

This is a fixed-length format.

Comment: Please explain (in words) the logic of the required transformation. Where  in your input is `BOA-t-12099` and `MPayment1017`?

Comment: Hi Michael, I've added an explanation above. Hope you understand what I am explaining :). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as your starting point:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/SyncCreditTransfer">
    <!-- Start of Header Record -->
        <!-- skipped for the purpose of this example -->
    <!-- End of Header Record -->
    <!-- Records -->
    <xsl:for-each select="Data/Record/Payment/Transaction">
        <!-- Start of Detail Record -->
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(CreditorParty/FinancialAccount/ID, 1 , 6)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(TransactionID, 1 , 8)"/>
        <xsl:text>099&#10;</xsl:text>
        <!-- End of Detail Record -->
        <!-- Start of Contra Record -->
        <xsl:value-of select="../DebtorParty/FinancialAccount/ID"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="../DisplayID"/>
        <xsl:text>017&#10;</xsl:text>
        <!-- End of Contra Record -->
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This still needs more work on the "contra" record, but you have not explained that part.

Note:

- the use of `xpath-default-namespace` to handle the namespace used by your input;
- the use of `xsl:for-each` to create a record for each transaction;

Note also that when the output method is text, using `xsl:element` makes no sense.